# Advanced Custom Fields foreach looping in opposite direction to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've been racking my brain on this one.

**Background:**

The following code works, and is grabbing the correct taxonomy term information for the relevant WordPress post.

**Problem:**

ACF is outputting terms in order of newest to oldest.
WordPress's $game->name; is outputting terms in order of oldest to newest.

This basically means that the tooltip is not matching the image from get_field('icon');

```
$games = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'games')

foreach ($games as $game) {
    $term = array_pop($games);
    if ( get_field('icon', $term) ) {
        echo '<img src="' . get_field('icon', $term ) . '" alt="' . $game->name . '" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . $game->name . '" />';
    }
}
```

I have so far tried:

- Updating $games to `$games = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'games', array( 'order' => 'DESC') )` (no impact).
- Reversing the order of the array for $games using array_reverse.

Suggestions would be enormously appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be deliberately doing this in your code by using `array_pop`??

Simply use the `$game` variable from your foreach loop:

```
$games = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'games')

foreach ($games as $game) {
    //$term = array_pop($games);
    if ( get_field('icon', $game) ) {
        echo '<img src="' . get_field('icon', $game ) . '" alt="' . $game->name . '" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . $game->name . '" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately array_pop() is needed to have this working, I've just removed it and nothing is returned in the loop. ACF documentation also uses this in their example - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

Comment: @Nick No, you must be doing something wrong. `array_pop` simply removes the last element from an array and returns it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php Did you make sure you change `$term` for `$game` throughout the foreach block, as above? especially in the if clause

Comment: you're absolutely right, thank you for highlighting the mistake. It's all working perfectly, really appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Nick No problem, glad i could help you